How to have author affiliations placed horizontally?
The following is MWE of my LaTeX file.
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{11}{14}}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\mdseries \fontsize{8}{9.6}}

\newcommand{\filliation}[5]{\affil[#1]{{#2}\vskip 0pt {#3}\vskip 0pt #4\vskip 0pt {{#5}} \vspace{10pt}}}

\title{Title of the Paper}
\author[1]{Author One}
\author[2]{Author Two}
\author[3]{Author Three}
\filliation{1}{Department}{University}{Adress}{email@email}
\filliation{2}{Department}{University}{Adress}{email@email}
\filliation{3}{Department}{University}{Adress}{email@email}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

This creates an output like-

But, I want the affiliations of the authors to be placed horizontally, like this-

How do I modify my MWE to have a format like this?

You can use the titlepage environment. Examples are included here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#More_titlepage_examples and also a link to a package.

This might not be the appropriate way but I have obtained the desired output by adding the following code snippet in the preamble of the file.
% Fix Author block and Affiliations
\usepackage{authblk}

\let\oldAuthfont\Authfont
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\fontsize{11}{14}\oldAuthfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\mdseries \fontsize{8}{9.6}}
\renewcommand\Authsep{, }
\renewcommand\Authand{, }
\renewcommand\Authands{, }


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent 0em%
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax\centering}% <--- Center the contents
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@author{
    \AB@authlist\\[\affilsep]
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-2em}
    \begin{multicols}{3} % <-- Change this based on number of author 
      \begin{quotation}
        \AB@affillist
      \end{quotation}
    \end{multicols}
    }
\makeatother

